# PuppeteerSharp часто появляется исключение NavigationException

Tags: c#, .net, puppeteer

Использую PuppeteerSharp для автоматизации работы с сайтами. Очень часто появляется одно из следующих исключений.

Session closed:

> PuppeteerSharp.NavigationException: Protocol error (Page.navigate):
> Session closed. Most likely the Page has been closed.Close reason:
> Target.detachedFromTarget ---> PuppeteerSharp.PuppeteerException:
> Protocol error (Page.navigate):  Session closed. Most likely the Page
> has been closed.Close reason: Target.detachedFromTarget    в
> PuppeteerSharp.CDPSession.d__32.MoveNext()    в
> C:\projects\puppeteer-sharp\lib\PuppeteerSharp\CDPSession.cs:строка 94

Browser has disconnected:

> PuppeteerSharp.NavigationException Navigation failed because browser
> has disconnected!  (Connection failed to process
> Runtime.executionContextCreated. Frame
> 59298DE19E589971C033B202FE166228 not found.        в
> PuppeteerSharp.Helpers.AsyncDictionaryHelper`2.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0()
> в
> C:\projects\puppeteer-sharp\lib\PuppeteerSharp\Helpers\AsyncDictionaryHelper.cs:строка
> 34    в
> PuppeteerSharp.Helpers.TaskHelper.d__6 1.MoveNext()    в
> C:\projects\puppeteer-sharp\lib\PuppeteerSharp\Helpers\TaskHelper.cs:строка
> 137

Но только при работе с каким-нибудь тяжёлым сайтом (например [Avito](http://www.avito.ru/)).
Исключение может появится при вызове любого метода `IBrowser` (например `WaitForSelectorAsync` или `ClickAsync`). Прежде чем выполнять следующее действие всегда дожидаюсь завершения выполнения предыдущего (то есть не может одновременно быть 2 вызова `WaitForSelectorAsync`). Находил описания решения подобной проблемы где говорилось что в этом может быть всё дело.

Загружаю браузер следующим образом:

```
await new BrowserFetcher().DownloadAsync();
PuppeteerHeadful = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions {
    Headless = false,
    Product = Product.Chrome,
    DefaultViewport = null,
    Args = new[] {
        "--disable-features=AudioServiceOutOfProcess",
        "--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled",
        "--window-size=" + windowSize
    }
});
```

Версия Chromium загружена самая последняя. Так же замечал проблему утечки памяти - после многократных запусков браузера даже если убить все процессы сильно увеличивается файл подкачки.